# No such file to load / Missing these required gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have an issue with a "missing gem".
After executing rake gems:install

```
 >> rake gems:install
(in /some/path)
gem install google-api-client --version "= 0.7.1"
Successfully installed uuidtools-2.1.5
Successfully installed google-api-client-0.7.1
2 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for uuidtools-2.1.5...
Installing ri documentation for google-api-client-0.7.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for uuidtools-2.1.5...
Installing RDoc documentation for google-api-client-0.7.1...
```

Where we can see with a gem list the presence of the gem

```
 >> gem list | grep google
google-api-client (0.7.1)
```

When starting my rail app I get a :

```
Missing these required gems:
  google-api-client  

You're running:
  ruby 1.8.7.302 at /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  rubygems 1.3.7 at /some/path/.gem/ruby/1.8, /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
```

and then Rails advices me to execute a "rake gems:install" to solve the issue..

I only have a single version of ruby installed : ruby 1.8.7-p302

```
 >> which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

 >> ls -l /usr/bin/ruby
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Aug 26  2013 /usr/bin/ruby -> ruby1.8

 >> ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]

 >> gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /root/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

I don't know where does the issue come from.

(Similarly, if I just make a ruby test file

```
require "rubygems"
require "google-api-client"
```

It outputs the same error :

```
 >> ruby test.rb 
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- google-api-client (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from test.rb:2
```

)

EDIT : I don't use bundle on this app.

Do you have some clue to solve this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Do bundle update before installing gem.

Comment: We do not use bundler with our app, nor we have a GemFile associated. I still can do a gem update...

Comment: Try sudo apt-get update before you run your rake tasks. It seems you have some dependency library files missing. Hope this helps.

Comment: Still nothing. performed apt-get update+upgrade and still missing. I'll give a look to the dependencies !

Comment: If you are using rails, then you *should* be using bundler - unless you **really** know what you're doing... but if you're suffering from gem dependency issues without knowing how to fix it... then you probably should just use bundler

Comment: That said: can you do an `ls` on `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems` and tell us if  `google-api-client` is listed there?

Comment: Also: `rubygems 1.3.7 at /some/path/.gem/ruby/1.8, /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8` Does that mean that you're running rubygems out of two possible different directories?

Comment: I'm working on the app of my company. :-) // google-api-client was listed // There is no .gem folder in /some/path !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it was just the require that was erroneous

```
require "google/api_client"
```

instead of

```
require "google-api-client"
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

You will update bundle version and then update gem.

Comment: I don't use Bundle. Even after gem update, the gem is still missing.